# Save single webelement to csv file or scrape display data to csv

Tags: python-3.x, excel, selenium, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

***hey I want to save scrape data into a CSV file problem is code is in selenium and this data are not scraped from the list, it is clicked page-scrape, and then next page-scrape how I save this data into CSV or I do save one by one ***

```
  for i in range(0,2):
    name=[]
    time.sleep(15)
    im = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-automation='CollectionGrid_item_link']")
    im[i].click()
    l = WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-track-label='contributorLink']")))
    print(l.text)
    n={'n':l.text}
    name.append(n)

    d=pd.DataFrame(name)
    d.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Fast Computer\Desktop\New folder\0.csv')
    driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code and you will see the problem:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    name = []
    l = 'a'
    n= {'n': l}
    name.append(n)
    print(i, name)
print(name)
```

You will see that `name` is created each time within loop and that you are only ever appending a single item.

Instead, move `name` outside the loop so that it is appended to during the loop:

```
import pandas as pd

name = []

for i in range(0,2):
    l = 'a'
    n = {'n': l}
    name.append(n)
    print(i, name)
print(name)
d = pd.DataFrame(name)
print(d)
```